# I need to select or read only .config files via file chooser in java fx can any one help me

Tags: javafx-2, filechooser

I need to get the file path of the .config folder only can any one help me

Comment: You need to add details on exactly `what you want`, `what you have tried` so far and `what doesn't work`. Unless you add these details, this question most probably will get closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `ExtensionFilter` to your `FileChooser` to select only .config files (or any type) via `FileChooser`.
e.g.

```
FileChooser flc = new FileChooser();
flc.setTitle("Select File");
ExtensionFilter ext = new ExtensionFilter("Config Files", "*.config");
flc.getExtensionFilters().add(ext);

File tmpFile = flc.showOpenDialog(stage);
```

You can set any extention type to the FileChooser.
e.g.

```
ExtensionFilter ext = new ExtensionFilter("Image Files", "*.png", "*.jpg", "*.jpeg");
```

Hope it helps.!